# WPF add shortcut to Controls.Page

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to bind two shortcut to functions of my code behind.

But those two functions are never called.

I Have the following implementation : 
Fitst NavigationWindow is called, it have a source property as follow :  `Source="MainPage.xaml"`

MainPage.xaml Code :

```
<Page x:Class="XXX.MainPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XXX"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
  Title="MainPage"  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Ctr1" Text="Another Text" />
        <RoutedUICommand x:Key="Ctr2" Text="Another Text" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>

<Page.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="F10" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{StaticResource Ctr1}" />
    <KeyBinding Key="F12" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{StaticResource Ctr2}" />
</Page.InputBindings>

<Page.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource Ctr1}" Executed="CtrShortcut1" />
    <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource Ctr2}" Executed="CtrShortcut2" />
</Page.CommandBindings>
<Grid/>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs Code :

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public void CtrShortcut1(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FONCTIONS.ShowToast("success", "test");
    }

    public void CtrShortcut2(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FONCTIONS.ShowToast("success", "test2");
    }
```

What did i do wrong ?

Is this even possible to bind shortcut on Page ?

---

EDIT

xaml code :

```
<Page.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="F12" Command="{Binding DoSomething}"/>
</Page.InputBindings>
```

xaml.cs code :

```
 public ICommand DoSomething { get; set; }        

    private void doSomething(object obj)
    {
        FONCTIONS.ShowToast("success", "Shortcut work !");
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        DoSomething = new RelayCommand(doSomething);
    }
```

---

SOLUTION
I fail to find a way to call shortcut from Controls.Page
But it's works with NavigationWindow and Window.
To get the page's contexte, i do a ref to my current page in static variable, then i call StaticVariable.Foo()

Page code :

```
  public static dynamic CurrentPage;
    public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            FONCTIONS.CurrentPage = this;
        }
```

And in my MainWindow code :

```
private void CurrentPageSetup1(object obj)
{
   REF_TO_STATIC_CLASS.CurrentPage.OpenSetup();
}
```

Comment: why dont you just implement an icommand to work along with your  keybindings?

Comment: I didn't manage to find a working exemple of icommand/keybindings implementation

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

XAML:

```
    <Window.InputBindings>
       <KeyBinding Key="F5" Command="{Binding DoSomething}"/> 
    </Window.InputBindings>
```

Code / Datacontext:

```
    public ICommand DoSomething{ get; set; }

    DoSomething= new RelayCommand(doSomething);

    private void doSomething(object obj)
    {
        //Make it happen
    }
```

i guess you already have a RelayCommand class? or do you need it as well?

EDIT 
here it is:

```
class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> execute;

    private readonly Predicate<object> canExecute;
    private ICommand setCommand;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(ICommand setCommand)
    {
        this.setCommand = setCommand;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
        {
            // ReSharper disable once LocalizableElement
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(execute), "Execute method missing");
        }

        this.execute = execute;
        this.canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
        }

        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
        }
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return this.canExecute?.Invoke(parameter) ?? true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have a RelayCommand class can you provide me an exemple ? (sorry it's my first wpf project)

Comment: added the class for your

Comment: It still doesn't work. If i understand well : In my XAML i bind a key to an ICommand. And in my constructor i create one instance of RelayCommand class with in parameter the function's name. But how do i do the link between the ICommand and the instance of RelayCommand ? (PS : i had to replace Window.InputBindings in Page.InputBindings)

Comment: i had a mistake in the answer that i corrected i forgot to change a name to doSomething 
just to make sure its not a page related issue try it on a window if the error still exists we got too look in a different direction

Comment: Everything in this code make sence now. It still doesn't work on Page, but it work on MainWindow. So the trouble come from Page. I had to call it from Page because i need to have access to Page instance.